# How to debug django-piston application?

Tags: django-piston

My piston application works correctly when I run it locally with python manage.py runserver command but returns

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403:
>   FORBIDDEN

under apache. How can I debug django-piston application?

Comment: Updating piston to the latest version solved the problem but it is still unclear how to debug piston app.

Answer (score 0):

I usually debug Piston apps by:

1. Setting my handlers to use Basic Authentication, even if I'm normally using something else.
2. Use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) to make requests
3. Use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) (or [ipdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb)) to set a breakpoint in my handler if desired.

You can conditionally change to BasicAuthentication like this:

```
auth = {'authentication': WhateverYouAreUsingForAuthentication(realm="YourSite")}

if getattr(settings, "API_DEBUG", None):
    from piston.authentication import HttpBasicAuthentication
    auth = {'authentication': HttpBasicAuthentication(realm="Spling")}

some_handler = Resource(SomeHandler, **auth)
```

To pass a username and password using curl, use the `-u` option:

```
curl -u username:password http://localhost:8000/api/some/endpoint/
```

So in your local settings module, just set `API_DEBUG=True` whenever you want to use basic auth.